# How to turn a pair of X, Y points in decimal into an image more accurately?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Normally this table is around 600 points but I didn't want to type it all, let's say I have points like this:

240.021000000000    291.414100000000

250.985100000000    297.566300000000

260.143500000000    310.125800000000

270.605100000000    315.355400000000

279.775500000000    327.352000000000

288.302300000000    335.765900000000

301.487400000000    348.374900000000

313.892100000000    340.501400000000

323.391400000000    328.044800000000

334.615100000000    322.182400000000

Where number on the left is X and number on the right is Y of a coordinate where there is a "thing" or let's say where the color is white and rest is black.

And I want to turn this into an image, what I did so far is this:

```
% Added 50 more pixels to not stick to edge of image
image = uint8(zeros(max(table(:, 1))+50, max(table(:, 2)+50))
for i = size(table(:))
image(round(table(i, 1)), round(table(i, 2))) = 256;
end
imshow(image);
```

I am wondering how accurate this is and how I can improve it or if I can improve it?

Reason here is I will do this for two tables and need to compare the similarity of two images that belong to these tables, but I don't even have an image and rounding didn't feel like the best way since 270.49999999 and 270.5000001 are similar, yet 270 and 271 are different. There can also be points that overlap each other if all is just rounded up or just rounded down.

Comment: I think you might find these posts useful: [Matlab - Creating a heatmap to visualize density of 2D point data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46996206/52738), [MATLAB - Pixelize a plot and make it into a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16006158/52738).

Comment: While this seems to work, it doesn't really create an greyscale image, it creates a plot. Which I can save as an image of course but it is still not the exact same thing I am looking for. I am looking to create a greyscale image from these data and right now I round up or down numbers. Instead I am trying to estimate how to create a better greyscale image. Maybe solution is to add a varying color between 270 and 271 X and 250 and 251 Y if data is something like 270.436323 and 250.757473? But not sure how.

Comment: Those answers do create grayscale images. The matrix data being passed to `imagesc` are effectively grayscale images.

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches, you can increase the resolution by binning your image to be N*600 by N*600 point instead of 600x600, for example 6000x6000, then each 0.1 value will be in  a different pixel. Or, you can convolve your 1 pixel with a distribution like a 5x5 Gaussian of signa=1  that will capture the spread around that point position. For example using `exp(- ((x-xn).^2+(x-yn).^2)/2)` where `xn` and `yn` are the n-th point coordinate in your question, and `x` and `y` are obtained via `[x y]=meshgrid(1:600)` or whatever your image size is....